# Android light theme with action bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use a light theme, but still have an actionbar visible.

From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) it looks like this should work:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
```

But when I add any android:theme the actionbar disappears.

I'm probably missing something obvious...

**Edit:** in case it helps

From the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/screen_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".owg">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textHeader"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#006699"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Empty set"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.java

```
package com.company.app;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class Main extends ListActivity { 
    private String[] mBooks = new String[]{ "Informational", "Extensions" };
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MySimpleArrayAdapter booksAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this,mBooks);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" ... >
```

instead of :

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
```

It should work. The issue here, that you use style without actionBar now, and there is some choices how action bar will look(see related styles)

```
//Use this to fill your action bar with items
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); 
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_name, menu); 
       return true;
}
```

or if yout want custom view for your actionBar

```
//Getting action bar
mActionBar = getActionBar();
```

and then use

```
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);//View object for your actionBar
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
```

**EDIT:** if you can't see title bar you can create it programmatically

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
activity.setTitle("Settings");
```

Comment: Sadly didn't work... added a little more info to see if helps any.

Comment: Post your activity(or fragment if you initialize action bar in it) code please

Comment: Added the action stuff. I'm not really sure where the action bar is being declared. It just shows up when no theme is in place, and disappears when I add a theme.

Comment: You should override this __ @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_name, menu);
     return true;
   } __ or you can simply do __mActionBar = getActionBar()__,  and then use  __mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
  mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);__

Comment: Could you edit your answer with that code? I'm extending ListActivity, not ActionBarActivity, so I don't know if that makes any difference with onCreateOptionsMenu. I did find this: `On API level 11 or higher
The action bar is included in all activities that use the Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants), which is the default theme when either the targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion attribute is set to "11" or higher. If you don't want the action bar for an activity, set the activity theme to Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.` which explains why I'm seeing it on the default theme.

Comment: You know, I wonder if what I need is title bar instead of action bar... I don't have any buttons or menu items, I just want to display the application title...